# Django: How to ignore tasks with Celery?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-settings, 12factor

Without changing the code itself, Is there a way to ignore tasks in Celery?

For example, when using Django mails, there is a [Dummy Backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#dummy-backend) setting. This is perfect since it allows me, from a `.env` file to deactivate mail sending in some environments (like testing, or staging). The code itself that handles mail sending is not changed with `if` statements or decorators.

For celery tasks, I know I could do it in code using mocks or decorators, but I'd like to do it in a clean way that is 12factors compliant, like with Django mails. Any idea?

#### EDIT to explain why I want to do this:

One of the main motivation behind this, is that it creates coupling between Django web server and Celery tasks.
For example, when running unit tests, if the broker server (Redis for me) is not running, then if `delay()` method is called, it freezes forever, because there is no timeout when Celery tries to send a task to Redis.
From an architecture view, this is very bad. I'd like my unit tests can run properly without the requirement to run a Celery broker!

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't run the celery worker, would the task run?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Please check my edit to understand the purpose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the coupling is concerned, your Django application would still be tied to celery if you use a dummy backend. Just your tasks won't execute. Maybe this is acceptable in your case but in my opinion, it can cause some problems. For example, if the piece of code you are trying to test, submits a task to celery, and in a later part, tries to retrieve the result for that task, it will fail. Because the dummy backend will never execute the task.

For unit testing, as you mentioned in your question, you can use the [task_always_eager](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_always_eager) setting. If you turn it on, your Django app will no longer depend upon a running worker. It will execute tasks in the same thread in a synchronous fashion and return the result.

Comment: `task_always_eager` is an excellent way to protect unit tests from freezing, thanks for the idea! And about the production code, how do you ensure there is no freezing if Redis is down? (in my case, background tasks are not business critical but web server is). I guess I should add a timeout and error logs when Celery tries to connect to redis.

Comment: @DavidD. Celery does not freeze if Redis (or whatever broker you are using) is down. It throws error immediately. However, if the worker is down, task is saved in the broker, and executed when worker is up.

Comment: Ohhh...I thought it was the default behaviour, but after some research, it seems to be a well known bug: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4296

Comment: @DavidD. Try to upgrade your celery version. I am not facing any such issues using celery 4.4.0.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question that was asked. Sure, I could enable `task_always_eager`, but say I have a function that doesn't rely on the result of a task that it calls. I don't want to waste time running that task inline during my tests, I just want the `apply_async()` or `delay()` call to be silently ignored. Ideally without mocking every single place in my program a task might be called (which might be via signal, etc.)

Comment: BTW, a method that seems to work for Redis is to modify `broker_url` when running tests so that tasks are placed into an unused DB index that the Celery workers are not listening on. That DB index can then be flushed after each test run.

Comment: @DustinMartin The OP was asking to create decoupling between broker and unit tests. How does placing tasks in *an unused DB index* create decoupling?
PS: You can still have that *unused DB index* without modifying the `broker_url`. Read the second comment.